# attr_accessor in method_missing

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm very new to Ruby and now trying to understand something about metaprogramming.
I want to return missed method name:

```
class Numeric

  attr_accessor :method_name

  def method_missing(method_id)
    method_name = method_id.to_s
    self
  end

  def name
    method_name
  end

end

10.new_method.name #this should return new_method, but returns nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your `method_missing`, `method_name` is being interpreted as a local variable rather than the `method_missing=` mutator method that you're expected. If you explicitly add the receiver then you'll get what you want:

```
def method_missing(method_id)
  self.method_name = method_id.to_s
  self
end
```

Alternatively, you could assign to the `@method_name` instance variable:

```
def method_missing(method_id)
  @method_name = method_id.to_s
  self
end
```

The `attr_accessor` macro just adds two methods for you so `attr_accessor :p` is shorthand for this:

```
def p
    @p
end
def p=(v)
    @p = v
end
```

You're free to use the underlying instance variable when you want or need to.